# xfce4 and Xrdp Server - Black Screen Kicks Session

Tags: 18.04, xfce, xrdp

I'm hoping someone can help me tackle this. I follow this tutorial here: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04/

When I rebooted after installing VirtualBox, I was no longer able to login to xfce. Once I filled in my user, and pass, it would go to black screen, and than kick the session.

I have a .xorgxrdp log which is as follows:

```
[  6781.396] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[  6781.396] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  6781.396] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[  6781.396] Current Operating System: Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64
[  6781.396] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.15.0-66-generic root=UUID=dafa7756-435e-418d-9fcd-34a73706a321 ro nomodeset quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[  6781.396] Build Date: 03 June 2019  08:10:35AM
[  6781.396] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  6781.396] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[  6781.396]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  6781.396] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  6781.396] (++) Log file: ".xorgxrdp.17.log", Time: Mon Nov 11 21:30:39 2019
[  6781.396] (++) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xrdp/xorg.conf"
[  6781.396] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  6781.396] (==) ServerLayout "X11 Server"
[  6781.396] (**) |-->Screen "Screen (xrdpdev)" (0)
[  6781.396] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor"
[  6781.397] (**) |   |-->Device "Video Card (xrdpdev)"
[  6781.397] (**) |-->Input Device "xrdpMouse"
[  6781.397] (**) |-->Input Device "xrdpKeyboard"
[  6781.397] (**) Option "DontVTSwitch" "on"
[  6781.397] (**) Option "AutoAddDevices" "off"
[  6781.397] (**) Not automatically adding devices
[  6781.397] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  6781.397] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  6781.397] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[  6781.397] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  6781.397] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  6781.397]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  6781.397] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  6781.397]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  6781.397] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  6781.397]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  6781.397] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  6781.397]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  6781.397] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  6781.397] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  6781.397] (II) Loader magic: 0x563ee0cb9020
[  6781.397] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  6781.397]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  6781.397]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[  6781.397]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  6781.397]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  6781.401] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c13
[  6781.411] (--) PCI:*(0:5:4:0) 1a03:2000:1170:0047 rev 16, Mem @ 0xfb000000/8388608, 0xfafe0000/131072, I/O @ 0x0000ec00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  6781.411] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[  6781.411] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[  6781.411] (II) Module "dbe" already built-in
[  6781.411] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[  6781.411] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[  6781.411] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[  6781.411] (II) Module "extmod" already built-in
[  6781.411] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  6781.411] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  6781.412] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  6781.412]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[  6781.412]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  6781.412] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[  6781.412] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[  6781.413] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  6781.413]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[  6781.413]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  6781.413] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[  6781.413] (II) Module "record" already built-in
[  6781.413] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[  6781.413] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[  6781.413] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  6781.413]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.1.0
[  6781.413]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  6781.413] (II) LoadModule: "xorgxrdp"
[  6781.413] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libxorgxrdp.so
[  6781.413] (II) Module XORGXRDP: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  6781.413]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[  6781.413]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  6781.413] xorgxrdpSetup:
[  6781.413] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  6781.413] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  6781.413] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  6781.413]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[  6781.413]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  6781.413] (II) LoadModule: "xrdpdev"
[  6781.413] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/xrdpdev_drv.so
[  6781.414] (II) Module XRDPDEV: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  6781.414]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[  6781.414]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  6781.414] xrdpdevSetup:
[  6781.414] (II) LoadModule: "xrdpmouse"
[  6781.414] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/xrdpmouse_drv.so
[  6781.414] (II) Module XRDPMOUSE: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  6781.414]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[  6781.414]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  6781.414]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[  6781.414] rdpmousePlug:
[  6781.414] (II) LoadModule: "xrdpkeyb"
[  6781.414] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/xrdpkeyb_drv.so
[  6781.414] (II) Module XRDPKEYB: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  6781.414]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[  6781.414]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  6781.414]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[  6781.414] rdpkeybPlug:
[  6781.414] rdpIdentify:
[  6781.414] (II) XRDPDEV: driver for xrdp: XRDPDEV
[  6781.414] rdpDriverFunc: op 10
[  6781.414] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for XRDPDEV
[  6781.414] rdpProbe:
[  6781.414] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  6781.414] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  6781.414] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  6781.414] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  6781.414]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[  6781.414]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  6781.414] (II) XRDPDEV(0): using default device
[  6781.414] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[  6781.414] rdpPreInit:
[  6781.414] (**) XRDPDEV(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[  6781.414] (==) XRDPDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[  6781.414] (==) XRDPDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  6781.414] (==) XRDPDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  6781.414] (==) XRDPDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[  6781.414] (II) XRDPDEV(0):   mode "640x480" ok
[  6781.414] (II) XRDPDEV(0):   mode "800x600" ok
[  6781.414] (--) XRDPDEV(0): Virtual size is 800x600 (pitch 800)
[  6781.414] (**) XRDPDEV(0):  Default mode "800x600": 36.0 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 35.2 kHz, 56.2 Hz
[  6781.414] (II) XRDPDEV(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz d)
[  6781.414] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[  6781.414] rdpScreenInit: virtualX 800 virtualY 600 rgbBits 8 depth 24
[  6781.414] rdpScreenInit: pfbMemory bytes 1920000
[  6781.414] rdpScreenInit: pfbMemory 0x7f0fc5e23010
[  6781.414] rdpSimdInit: assigning yuv functions
[  6781.414] rdpSimdInit: cpuid ax 1 cx 0 return ax 0x000206c2 bx 0x02200800 cx 0x029ee3ff dx 0xbfebfbff
[  6781.415] rdpSimdInit: sse2 amd64 yuv functions assigned
[  6781.415] rdpXvInit: depth 24
[  6781.415] (==) XRDPDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[  6781.415] rdpClientConInit: kill disconnected [0] timeout [0] sec
[  6781.415] 
[  6781.415] rdpScreenInit: out
[  6781.415] (==) RandR enabled
[  6781.418] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  6781.418] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[  6781.418] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[  6781.467] (II) IGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[  6781.468] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[  6781.468] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[  6781.502] (II) Using input driver 'XRDPMOUSE' for 'xrdpMouse'
[  6781.502] (**) Option "CorePointer"
[  6781.502] (**) xrdpMouse: always reports core events
[  6781.502] rdpmousePreInit: drv 0x563ee1f05e70 info 0x563ee2208e10, flags 0x0
[  6781.502] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "xrdpMouse" (type: Mouse, id 6)
[  6781.502] rdpmouseControl: what 0
[  6781.502] rdpmouseDeviceInit:
[  6781.502] rdpmouseCtrl:
[  6781.502] rdpRegisterInputCallback: type 1 proc 0x7f0fc61fcc60
[  6781.503] (**) xrdpMouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[  6781.503] (**) xrdpMouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[  6781.503] (**) xrdpMouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[  6781.503] (**) xrdpMouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[  6781.503] rdpmouseControl: what 1
[  6781.503] rdpmouseDeviceOn:
[  6781.503] (II) Using input driver 'XRDPKEYB' for 'xrdpKeyboard'
[  6781.503] (**) Option "CoreKeyboard"
[  6781.503] (**) xrdpKeyboard: always reports core events
[  6781.503] rdpkeybPreInit: drv 0x563ee1f05de0 info 0x563ee220b9b0, flags 0x0
[  6781.503] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "xrdpKeyboard" (type: Keyboard, id 7)
[  6781.503] rdpkeybControl: what 0
[  6781.503] rdpkeybDeviceInit:
[  6781.525] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
[  6781.525] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat on
[  6781.525] rdpRegisterInputCallback: type 0 proc 0x7f0fc5ff9530
[  6781.525] rdpkeybControl: what 1
[  6781.525] rdpkeybDeviceOn:
[  6781.536] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[  6781.536] (II) AutoAddDevices is off - not adding device.
[  6781.537] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[  6781.537] (II) AutoAddDevices is off - not adding device.
[  6781.538] (II) config/udev: Adding input device American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse (/dev/input/event2)
[  6781.538] (II) AutoAddDevices is off - not adding device.
[  6781.538] (II) config/udev: Adding input device American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse (/dev/input/event3)
[  6781.538] (II) AutoAddDevices is off - not adding device.
[  6781.539] (II) config/udev: Adding input device American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse (/dev/input/js0)
[  6781.539] (II) AutoAddDevices is off - not adding device.
[  6781.540] (II) config/udev: Adding input device American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[  6781.540] (II) AutoAddDevices is off - not adding device.
[  6781.547] rdpSaveScreen:
[  6781.547] rdpDeferredRandR:
[  6781.547] rdpResizeSession: width 1024 height 768
[  6781.547]   calling RRScreenSizeSet
[  6781.547] rdpRRScreenSetSize: width 1024 height 768 mmWidth 271 mmHeight 203
[  6781.547] rdpRRGetInfo:
[  6781.547]   screen resized to 1024x768
[  6781.548]   RRScreenSizeSet ok 1
[  6781.548] rdpResizeSession: width 1920 height 1080
[  6781.548]   calling RRScreenSizeSet
[  6781.548] rdpRRScreenSetSize: width 1920 height 1080 mmWidth 508 mmHeight 286
[  6781.549] rdpRRGetInfo:
[  6781.549]   screen resized to 1920x1080
[  6781.553]   RRScreenSizeSet ok 1
[  6781.553] rdpClientConGotConnection:
[  6781.553] rdpClientConGotConnection: g_sck_accept ok new_sck 7
[  6781.553] rdpClientConGotConnection: adding only clientCon
[  6781.553] rdpClientConProcessMsgVersion: version 0 0 0 1
[  6781.553] rdpClientConProcessScreenSizeMsg: set width 1920 height 1080 bpp 32
[  6781.553] rdpClientConProcessScreenSizeMsg: shmemid 262151 shmemptr 0x7f0f96014000
[  6781.553] rdpClientConProcessMsgClientInput: invalidate x 0 y 0 cx 1920 cy 1080
[  6781.553] KbdSync: toggling num lock
[  6781.553] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
[  6781.553] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat on
[  6781.653] rdpInDeferredUpdateCallback:
[  6781.653] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
[  6781.653] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat off
[  6798.004] rdpClientConProcessMsgClientInfo:
[  6798.004]   got client info bytes 5744
[  6798.004]   jpeg support 0
[  6798.004]   offscreen support 1
[  6798.004]   offscreen size 10485760
[  6798.004]   offscreen entries 100
[  6798.004]   client can not do offscreen to offscreen blits
[  6798.004]   client can do new(color) cursor
[  6798.004]   client can not do multimon
[  6798.004] rdpRRSetRdpOutputs: numCrtcs 0 monitorCount 0
[  6798.004] rdpRRSetRdpOutputs: add output 0 left 0 top 0 width 1920 height 1080
[  6798.004] rdpLoadLayout: keylayout 0x00000409 variant  display 17
[  6798.005] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
[  6798.005] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat on
[  6798.005] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
[  6798.005] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat on
[  6798.105] rdpInDeferredUpdateCallback:
[  6798.105] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
[  6798.105] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat off
[  6798.105] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
[  6798.105] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat off
[  7116.314] KbdSync: toggling num lock
[  7116.314] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
[  7116.314] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat on
[  7116.314] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
[  7116.314] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat off
[  7116.414] rdpInDeferredUpdateCallback:
[  7116.414] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
[  7116.414] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat off
[  7116.414] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl:
[  7116.414] rdpkeybChangeKeyboardControl: autoRepeat off
[  7118.731] rdpClientConRecv: g_sck_recv failed(returned 0)
[  7118.731] rdpClientConDisconnect:
[  7118.731] rdpClientConDisconnect: clientCon removed from dev list
[  7118.731] rdpClientConRecvMsg: error
[  7118.731] rdpClientConCheck: rdpClientConGotData failed
```

Comment: Check you have space in $HOME (your user directory).  If it's what I thinking of, you'll be able to login to text terminal to check, but GUI requires work files to be created; if the creation of these fails; login fails & you're back at greeter (no error messages).

Comment: @guiverc I notice I don't have any .xsession files and those are noted all over the net when I'm searching. But I also don't have /etc/gdm present.

Comment: Edit your question and add any additional information you have there (where most people look).  The only file I have in my ~ ($HOME directory) is ~/.xsession-errors  (*which if it doesn't exist; I believe will be created*).  I don't know the instructions you followed, but lots of people don't use the 25GB minimum suggested and after adding software the lack of space is a common issue (unless it's a result of something else you didn't mention found in your `history`)

Comment: How do you check the space of `$HOME` specifically? There is the `sda` and `sdb` partitions at 1.8 terrabytes, and than boot and swap and sda5 which is just listed as `sda`'s limit.

Comment: `df -h |grep sda` maybe; df ~= disk free; -h = human readable numbers, grep to sda.   If you have no /home partition then it'll go in / which means adding software or data can cause gui login to fail.. (as can saving too much data for your partitions too)

Comment: /dev/sda5       1.8T  8.6G  1.7T   1% /
/dev/sda1       945M   58M  839M   7% /boot

Is the pull response. Ironically, I removed .xsession-errors and all the past error files for sessions that were empty, and it seems to have logged in while attempting to get fresh errors. Nothing really changed besides removing error files... I don't even know.

Comment: If you didn't own the ~/.xsession-errors (eg. you'd used `sudo` to do something with it and as consequence changed ownership to root instead of you) removing the file so it could be re-created would have worked (a better fix would have been changing ownership (`chown`) back to you).  Space does **not** appear to have been your issue though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot be certain as to the original exact cause, but I assume as guiverc mentioned I likely did something with the root account and changed the ownership of my xsession files. Namely, I removed the ~/.xsessions-errors file, and created a new one under the correct user which seemed to have fixed the problem for me, though to be sure I took ownershp of all the xsession files after I had gotten into the desktop.